# Выделение строки treeview

Tags: delphi

Уважаемые программисты, хотел поинтересоваться: возможно ли постоянно выделять строку treeview, не зависимо передан фокус этому компоненту или нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выбор цвета оставляю за вами

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  if cdsSelected in State then
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clWindow;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  end
  else   
  begin
    Sender.Canvas.Font.Color := clWindow;
    Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed; 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @praddos, прошу прощения за назойливость, но хотелось бы знать, а у TListBox можно сделать то же самое? События CustomDrawItem у него к сожалению нет.

Comment: @АлександрЪ, там по событию ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState) попробуйте

Answer (score 2):

Выделение элемента в **TreeView** без потери выделенного элемента при потере фокуса))

```
with TreeView1 do
begin
  SetFocus;
  Selected := Items[1];
  HideSelection :=False; //без этого выделяет, но при потере фокуса выделенный элемент становится, как все остальные))
end;
```

Comment: с этим согласен, но при потере фокуса выделение теряется, а возможно ли его сохранить?

Comment: добавь
TreeView1.HideSelection :=False;
и выделение не будет терятся

Comment: работает, но так оно становиться светло-серым, а возможно оставить синим, как по стандарту? Или вообще возможно цвет поменять?

Comment: можно, но я не знаю как

Answer (score 0):

1 вариант :

```
Cl: TColor;
…
If stileservice.avalaible then
Cl:= stileservice.getstilecolor(scTreeView);
…
```

Comment: TStyleColor ( in style forms in application ) .

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это разве ответ на заданный вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

второй вариант:

```
procedure TCustomDrawForm.TVCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView; Node: TTreeNode;
  State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  NodeRect: TRect;
begin
  with TV.Canvas do
  begin
{
    If DefaultDraw is True, any of the node's font 
    properties can be changed. Note also that when 
    DefaultDraw = True, Windows draws the buttons and 
    ignores your setted font background colors, using 
    instead the TreeView's Color property.
    if cdsSelected in State then
    begin
      Font.Assign(SelectedFontDialog.Font);
      Brush.Color := SelBkgColorDialog.Color;
    end;

    DefaultDraw := False; // FDefaultDrawItem;
{
    DefaultDraw = False means that you have to handle 
    all the item drawing yourself, including the buttons,
    lines, images, and text.
    if not DefaultDraw then
    begin
      //Draw the selection rect.
      if cdsSelected in State then
      begin
        NodeRect := Node.DisplayRect(True);
        FillRect(NodeRect);
      end;
      NodeRect := Node.DisplayRect(False);

      if None1.Checked then
      //No bitmap available, so paint in the background color.
      begin
        Brush.Color := BkgColorDialog.Color;
        Brush.Style := FBrushStyle;
        FillRect(NodeRect)
      end
      else
        //Do not paint over the background bitmap.
        Brush.Style := bsClear;

      NodeRect.Left := NodeRect.Left + (Node.Level * TV.Indent);
      // NodeRect.Left now represents the leftmost portion 
      // of the expand button.
      DrawButton(NodeRect, Node); // See the CustomDraw demo.

      NodeRect.Left := NodeRect.Left + TV.Indent + FButtonSize;
      //NodeRect.Left is now the leftmost portion of the image.
      DrawImage(NodeRect, Node.ImageIndex); // See the CustomDraw demo.

      NodeRect.Left := NodeRect.Left + ImageList.Width;
      //Now you are finally in the position to draw the text.

      TextOut(NodeRect.Left, NodeRect.Top, Node.Text);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit] // p.s. стоило не создавать новый ответ, а дополнить предыдущий.