# Как изменить цвет выделения в TreeView для стиля TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS?

Tags: delphi, winapi, treeview

У `TreeView` есть стиль `TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS`, позволяющий подсвечивать выбранный пункт, даже когда `TreeView` не имеет фокуса. Однако для подсветки используется серый цвет. Можно ли, изменить его на синий, который используется для выделения пункта, когда `TreeView` имеет фокус?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно обрабатывать сообщение `WM_NOTIFY`, для получения указателя на структуру `NMHDR`, взятого из `lParam`. Если переменные `idFrom` и `code`, указателя данной структуры, соответственно равны `идентификатор_tree_view` и `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` , то далее нужно получить указатель на структуру `NMTVCUSTOMDRAW` из `lParam`. Если переменная `dwDrawStage` (под-структура `nmcd`, указателя `LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW`), равна `CDDS_PREPAINT`, то необходимо возвратить `CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW` как сообщение и результат обработчика оконной функции. А при `nmcd` = `CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT`, проверять переменную `uItemState`под-структуры `nmcd`, и если в ней содержится значение `CDIS_SELECTED`, то нужно изменить значения переменных `clrText` и `clrTextBk`, в указателе `LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW`, на `белый` и `синий` цвета (в формате `BGR`) соответственно, и вернуть `CDRF_NEWFONT` в качестве результата обработчика оконной функции.

[Пример кода](http://ideone.com/dDEJUU):

```delphi
function WndProc(Wnd:HWND; uMsg:Integer; wParam:WPARAM; lParam:LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall; 
  ...
  if uMsg = WM_NOTIFY then
    with PNMHDR(lParam)^ do
      //  выбираем свой TreeView
      if (idFrom = idMyTreeView) and (code = NM_CUSTOMDRAW) then
      begin
        with LPNMTVCUSTOMDRAW(lParam)^.nmcd do
          case dwDrawStage of
            CDDS_PREPAINT:
            begin
              // говорим системе, что хотим обработать CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT
              Result:=CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;
              Exit;
            end;
            CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
            begin
              //  обрабатываем состояние выделения
              if (uItemState and CDIS_SELECTED) <> 0 then
              begin
                clrText:=$ffffff;  //  задаем цвет текста
                clrTextBk:=$c56a31;//  задаем цвет фона
              end;
              Result:=CDRF_NEWFONT;
            end;
          end;
      end;
  ...
```

Comment: А не проще было это все заменить на пару строк кода?

Comment: Код пишется на конкретном ЯП, в то время, как другой пользователь может использовать при программировании, ЯП, отличный от указанного. Я привёл структурное описание решения данного вопроса... А каждый, кто столкнётся с данной проблемой, может написать код на необходимом ему языке программирования.

Comment: Вы текстом описали логику работы решения, но **текстом** ничего такого не добавили, что нельзя было бы показать кодом. Код более лаконичен, его быстрее и проще понять. Напишите на любом `ЯП`, какой Вам удобнее, я добавлю его к меткам вопроса. И еще, обещаю `+1`, если вместо текста будет код.

Comment: Пытался написать чистый код (путём вырезания фрагментов из основного кода программы) для иллюстрации решения, но он получается настолько громоздким, так как среда программирования, в которой я работаю, содержит не все типы и константы WinApi, и приходится добавлять ещё большие фрагменты, для их определения... Как считаете, может всё-таки лучше оставить словесное описание, или надо добавить код?

Comment: Тут не нужен "чистый код". Нужно просто кодом выразить те мысли, которые вы описали словами. Если есть еще и рабочий код, то приводить его не надо. Можно просто дать ссылку на него в https://ideone.com/, например.

Comment: Добавил фрагмент кода, который я описал словами в решении.

Comment: Эх опоздал с ответом, но вот я отвечал на похожий вопрос @http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/309323/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-treeview/309921#309921

Comment: **Praddos**, ничего страшного. Благодарю за комментарий.


**mega**, спасибо что помогли оформить код!